# System.JSONException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR,code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash

Tags: apex, json

I'm writing test class and i'm trying to give a json content to my controller but i get the error mentionned in the title should i replace all the " by \"  ??? i have already tried by i still get the same error

```
 controller.postDATA = '{"entries":{"XD-ZESFS":{"filename":"XD-ZESFS.xir","content":"[Product]\r\nSerialNumber = NEUtOTUzMzM=\r\nMacAdd = AB5nG66S\r\nCpuId = AAIGwr/r+/8AnOP9\r\nSerialText = XD-ZESFS\r","SN":"4E-953330","Status":-1,"id":null,"product":""}},"ct":3,"snList":["XD-ZESFS"]}';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it means you need to add an additional backslash in front of them.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out and I answered my question but thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I just found the inswer in the link below actually I had to double the backslashes 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json